# C#(Mono)でgzip圧縮データをHttpWebRequest.GetResponseで取得するには

Tags: c#, unity3d

UnityのC#(Mono)でサーバー側でgzip圧縮されたデータをHttpWebRequestのGetResponse()メソッドを使用して受け取りたいです。

下記のソースの
　**using (HttpWebResponse wres = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())**
を実行すると、
　**DllNotFoundException: MonoPosixHelper**　
というエラーが出てレスポンスを受け取ることができません。

調査したところ、MonoにはGZipStreamの名前空間はいるようなのですが実装部はいないようです。
※なぜならコンパイルは通りますが、GzipStreamを使用しようとすると落ちるのでInterFaceのみいるのではないかと思ってます。

リクエスト側はIonic.Zip.CF.dllを使用してgzip圧縮し、サーバー側にデータを送信する事はできたのですが、下記スタックトレースを見たところGetResponse()メソッドはSystem.IO.Compression.GZipStream をコールするようにできているみたいで回避する方法がわかりません。

開発環境：Windows7 Unity5.0.2f1

●ソースコード

```
string serialized = Json.Serialize(JsonDataDic);
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("APIのURL");

req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
req.Method = "POST";
req.Accept = "application/json";
req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentEncoding, "gzip");
byte[] text = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serialized);
byte[] compress = Compress(text);
req.ContentLength = compress.Length;
// データの設定
var s = req.GetRequestStream();
s.Write(compress, 0, compress.Length);
s.Close();

HttpWebResponse wresa = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

using (HttpWebResponse wres = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream st = wres.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int count = 0;
            do
            {
                count = st.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);

            } while (count != 0);
            string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());

            var deserializedDoubleList = Json.Deserialize(str) as Dictionary<string, object>;
        }
    }
}
```

●スタックトレース

```
DllNotFoundException: MonoPosixHelper
System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream..ctor (System.IO.Stream compressedStream, CompressionMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Boolean gzip)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream:.ctor (System.IO.Stream,System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode,bool,bool)
System.IO.Compression.GZipStream..ctor (System.IO.Stream compressedStream, CompressionMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen)
System.IO.Compression.GZipStream..ctor (System.IO.Stream compressedStream, CompressionMode mode)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.Compression.GZipStream:.ctor (System.IO.Stream,System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode)
System.Net.HttpWebResponse..ctor (System.Uri uri, System.String method,     System.Net.WebConnectionData data, System.Net.CookieContainer container)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Net.HttpWebResponse:.ctor (System.Uri,string,System.Net.WebConnectionData,System.Net.CookieContainer)
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data)
Rethrow as WebException: MonoPosixHelper
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult)
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse ()
```

Comment: リクエストにAccept-Encoding: gzipが含まれていなければサーバーがgzipエンコーディングでレスポンスを返すことはないはずですが。

Comment: gzip圧縮でレスポンスを返して欲しいのですが、gzipデータだと認識はしないで欲しいのです。　自動的にgzipファイルだと認識されるとMonoだとエラーになってしまうのです。

Comment: @sayuri リクエストに`Accept-Encoding: gzip`が含まれていない場合でも、gzipでレスポンスが返される可能性はあります。`Accept-Encoding`を省略したときはレスポンスのエンコーディングに指定がないという意味なので、gzipで返してもHTTP/1.1の仕様上問題はありません。

Comment: Accept-Encoding: gzip　を含まないようにリクエストを作り、サーバー側でgzip圧縮して返してもらうことでできました。　圧縮したデータを送り・圧縮されたデータを受け取るAPIが実現できました。

Answer (score 1):

`Accept-Encoding: gzip`を含まないようにリクエストを作り、サーバー側でgzip圧縮して返してもらうことで、圧縮したデータを送り・圧縮されたデータを受け取るAPIが実現できました。

---

<sup>この投稿は @user3732298 さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/11040/cmono%e3%81%a7gzip%e5%9c%a7%e7%b8%ae%e3%83%87%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%82%92httpwebrequest-getresponse%e3%81%a7%e5%8f%96%e5%be%97%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ab%e3%81%af#comment10170_11040)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>